# How do I unlock kwallet automatically on login

Tags: kubuntu, login, kwallet

Running Kubuntu 17.04.

I do not have automatic login and have to enter my password to login.

On login, I am prompted for the password of my kwallet (It is the same as my login password).

How do I unlock the kwallet automatically on login?

Comment: Are you logging in automatically?

Comment: … if so, you can't unlock kwallet automatically due to security reasons.

Comment: @MichaelBay No. I am not logging in automatically. I need to enter my password for logging in.

Comment: When you provide additional information, please do remember to update your question as well.

Comment: @DKBose, done, as suggested.

Comment: What is the output of `ps axjf | grep --color=auto kwallet`?

Comment: @DKBose here it is:

$ ps axjf | grep --color=auto kwallet
    1  4499  4498  4498 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00 /usr/bin/kwalletd --pam-login 15 18 --nofork
    1  4501  4500  4500 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:00 /usr/bin/kwalletd5 --pam-login 15 19
 6222  6254  6253  6222 pts/8     6253 S+    1000   0:00      \_ grep --color --color=auto kwallet

And as if by miracle, on restarting the computer, I did not have to enter the password the second time to unlock kdewallet

Comment: @DKBose the problem has resurfaced. The output of `ps` command is the same. But it complains that kded5 needs to access kdewallet and I have to enter the password twice every time I restart the computer.

Comment: @deshmukh did you find a solution? same problem here.

Comment: @Piu130 I had to reinstall my OS. No problem since then